# Verify the sign of `DiracDelta`

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

[The Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Inhomogeneous_Helmholtz_equation) reads:

$$
(\nabla^2+1)g(\vec{r})=-\delta(\vec{r})
$$

with $\delta(\vec{r})$ being the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

The solution of above equation is:
$$
g(\vec{r})=\frac{e^{i r}}{4\pi r}
$$

I want to verify the equation by mathematica, it is not hard to verify the general cases. i.e. $r\neq0$. Below is the code:

```
(*Helmolholz equation*)
g[x,y,z]=Exp[I Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]]/(4 Pi  Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]);
minusG[x,y,z]=-Exp[I Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]]/(4 Pi  Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]);
op=(D[#,{x,2}]+D[#,{y,2}]+D[#,{z,2}]+#)&;
op[g[x,y,z]]//Simplify
op[minusG[x,y,z]]//Simplify


(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
```

As show above, both $g(\vec{r})$ and $-g(\vec{r})$ satisfies the above equation when $r\neq0$. **How can I manipulate Mathematica, so that is can discard the `wrong` answer $-g(\vec{r})$**

Comment: Taking a Fourier transform of the equation should work I think.

Comment: @march It is time consuming and I haven't got an answer yet.  The code :`FourierTransform[g[x, y, z], {x, y, z}, {kx, ky, kz}]` is still running...

Comment: It is actually any $\alpha g(\vec r)$ satisfies your equation for $r\neq0$. You need to check the normalization of the left side.

Comment: Ideally, this should be a job for `GreenFunction`, but it doesn't seem to work in 3D. The 2D Helmholtz equation is actually treated in the documentation.

Comment: @yarchik yeah, this is also a problem.

Comment: @Jens This is only implemented in v11

Comment: It's *partially* implemented in version 11. Not for 3D, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a satisfactory symbolic solution for your problem. You can try some numerics:

```
(* Approximate g by adding an epsilon parameter *)
g[x_, y_, z_, ϵ_] = Exp[I (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + ϵ^2])] \
                    / (4 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + ϵ^2]);
op = (D[#, x, x] + D[#, y, y] + D[#, z, z] + #) &;
opg[x_, y_, z_, ϵ_] = op[g[x, y, z, ϵ]] // Simplify;
opmg[x_, y_, z_, ϵ_] = op[-g[x, y, z, ϵ]] // Simplify;
(* Check numerically that the solution satisfies the expected condition *)
NIntegrate[opg[x, y, z, 10^-10], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}, WorkingPrecision->17]
NIntegrate[opmg[x, y, z, 10^-10], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}, WorkingPrecision->17]
```

Integrations took 108 seconds (total for both) on my Core i7-4765T and yielded this:

> -0.99999999985411509 + 0.*10^-20 I
>
> 0.99999999985411509 + 0.*10^-20 I

As you can see, indeed `op[g]` integrates to `-1`, while `op[-g]` integrates to `1`. And symbolic simplifications of `op[g]`, which don't assume `g` to be a distribution, yield `0`. Thus indeed `g` behaves like $-(1-p)\delta(\cdot)$, where the error $p\approx1.46\cdot10^{-10}.$

Comment: This is a very clever workaround.

Comment: My cpu is Intel(R) Pentium(R)  2020M, and I only used `46.372` second with your code.

Comment: @buzhidao I meant total for both integrals, one of which was forgotten to be pasted. But of course you can see the result even from single integral, since the integrands only differ by sign.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is actually provided by the comment of march. There is no much to add, except probably to show how the Fourier transform can actually be computed with Mathematica. Let us notice first that in the Fourier space the slightly generalized identity

$(\nabla^2+a^2)e^{i a r}/r=-\delta(\vec r)$

looks as follow:

$-k^2f(\vec k)+a^2f(\vec k)\equiv-k^2/(k^2 -a^2)+a^2/(k^2 -a^2)=-1$,

where we use the fact that application of $\vec\nabla$ yields $i\vec k$ in the Fourier space, and $\Delta \equiv \vec\nabla^2\rightarrow-k^2$.

Thus, we need to show that the Fourier transform of your Green's function is exactly $1/(k^2 -a^2)$. One can do it in spherical coordinates, integration over $\phi$ gives a prefactor of $2\pi$. Remaining integrals are as follows:

```
Integrate[ 1/2 r Exp[I (k x + a) r], {x,-1,1},{r,0,\[Infinity]}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```